# Firefox showing "connection is not secure" for rss page

Tags: firefox, rss, connection

I have a site which is using https and certificate is added for same.
Site shows secure connection for all pages in Google Chrome but for Firefox it is showing connection is insecure for Rss feed page. 
For rest of all pages it is showing secure connection in fire fox too.

I did googled lot but didn't found any help. Can anybody help for this?
Thanks in advance.